# Google Script - Help in having setValue change every 10 matched rows

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, setvalue

Building on my previous question relating to this script below. Is it possible to setValue to change after 10 matches, I would like to assign "found here" for the first 10 matches, then "something else" for another 10 matches, then "another phrase" for 10, and then critically to repeat. Thus every match is set a value that changes every 10 matched rows  -

```
function onSearch() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Sheet");
    var searchVal1 = sheet.getRange("AE31").getValue();
    var searchVal2 = sheet.getRange("AE32").getValue();
    var searchVal3 = sheet.getRange("AE33").getValue();
    var searchCol1 = sheet.getRange(2,6,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var searchCol2 = sheet.getRange(2,7,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();    
    var searchCol3 = sheet.getRange(2,7,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); 
    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol1.length; i < len; i++) 
    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)

{if (searchVal1 === "")
      (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
       else if (searchCol1[i][0] == searchVal1)
{if (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
    {if (searchVal2 === "")
      (searchCol3[i][0] == searchVal3)
       else if (searchCol2[i][0] == searchVal2)
{if (searchVal3 === "")
      else if (searchCol3[i][0] == searchVal3) 

{sheet.getRange(i + 2, 30).setValue("found here")
```

This is an example of the data set i am using - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CAflyzAIyb5Fuz3Ef2sLbhfFO9DXSNIVIh0h7uBEFQo/edit?usp=sharing
Any and all help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think is to set another variable and make it increase every time setValue() is run, checking the value against the desired outputs.

```
var outCount = 0;
var outVal;

if(outCount < 10){
  outVal = "found here";
} else if(outCount < 20){
  outVal = "something else";
} else if(outCount < 30) {
  outVal = "another phrase";
}
...
sheet.getRange(i + 2, 30).setValue("found here");
outCount++;
```

Does that fully solve the issue, or is there more I'm missing?